# Automatic organization of buttons on a screen

Tags: javafx

I have a screen created by code, in that screeen i will add 1 at N...buttons, but a wold like to they buttons self organize on screen, taking up all the screen space. But when add button, they are added in a single queue.

[image]

```
Stage primaryStage = (Stage) btActivity1.getScene().getWindow();

        Stage stageLayout = new Stage();
        stageLayout.setHeight(primaryStage.getHeight());
        stageLayout.setWidth(primaryStage.getWidth());
        stageLayout.setMaximized(false);

        stageLayout.setTitle("Layout: " + cbListOfRouter.getValue().getSerie());
        stageLayout.initOwner(primaryStage);
        stageLayout.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL); 
        
        HBox box = new HBox();
        box.setStyle("-fx-background-color: gainsboro; -fx-border-color: gainsboro; -fx-background-radius: 10; -fx-border-radius: 10");
        box.setPadding(new Insets(10, 20, 10, 20));
        box.setSpacing(5);
        box.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
        box.getChildren().addAll(createButtonsLayout());
        box.getChildren().add(new Button());
        
        Vector<Button> listWoButtons = createButtonsLayout();
        int count = 1;
        
        for (Button bt : listWoButtons) {
            box.getChildren().add(bt);
            count++;
        }

        stageLayout.setScene(new Scene(box));
        stageLayout.showAndWait();
```

Comment: Use a `FlowPane` instead of a `HBox`

Comment: Thak you James, its worked very well

Answer (score 3):

Its worked well

```
FlowPane box = new FlowPane();
        box.setStyle("-fx-background-color: gainsboro; -fx-border-color: gainsboro; -fx-background-radius: 10; -fx-border-radius: 10");
        box.setPadding(new Insets(10, 20, 10, 20));
        //box.setSpacing(5);
        box.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
        box.getChildren().addAll(createButtonsLayout());
```

[image]